# Image is not shwing in the user profile in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am having a little problem here. I am trying to put an image in my User Profile. The image is saved in the database and no errors are shown up, but I never see the default image that I gave to it. It says that it's there but The place for the pic stays empty.

This is what I've got for now:

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// namespace App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

// use App\Http\Requests\Request;

// use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function profile()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('profile',compact('user',$user));
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();

        $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);

        $user->avatar = $avatarName;
        $user->save();

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');

    }
        /** Return view to upload file */
        public function uploadFile(){
            return view('uploadfile');
        }

            /** Example of File Upload */
    public function uploadFilePost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'fileToUpload' => 'required|file|max:1024',
        ]);

        $request->fileToUpload->store('logos');

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');

    }
}
```

profile.blade.pbp

```
<hidden='Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth'>

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>

                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>

                </div>

            @endif

            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <div class="profile-header-container">
                <div class="profile-header-img">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" width="150" height="150" src="/storage/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" />
                    <!-- badge -->
                    <div class="rank-label-container">
                        <span class="label label-default rank-label">{{$user->name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="avatar" id="avatarFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please upload a valid image file. Size of image should not be more than 2MB.</small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

filesystems.php

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
```

How can I make the default avatar visible?

Also, do you have any suggestions on how to put a watermark on the photos that will appear each time someone uploads photos?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `src="/storage/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}"` require a `public`  beforehand? Have you created shortcuts for these image resources or is it just storing in `storage`? Also, does `$user` has the updated avatar value?

Comment: execute this command `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes, it's a public one it's just storing in the storage, didn't know I needed shortcuts, and as a new to Laravel, I am not quite sure how to make them... Yes, the $user has the updated avatar value.

Comment: @A.ANoman thank you, but that Is already done :), if you have some other advice I am listening.

Comment: Also, I am not finding anything helpful for putting watermarks on the uploaded from the user images, can you give some suggestions if you have used watermarks in Laravel before?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. First execute this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then

```
<img class="rounded-circle" width="150" height="150" src="{{url('')}}/storage/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}"/>
```

Comment: It's still an empty space until I (as a user) don't upload my own photo/image/pic.